# Azure function in KEDA does not use virtual kubelet nodes

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless, keda

I am trying to use Azure function using KEDA for auto scaling and make the container run in virtual kubelets to save cost. Even when I taint the nodes to virtual kubelet, it still runs in my node agent. I have virtual node installed.

[image]

It is simple queue trigger function and the tainting and toleration in deploy.yaml are as below.

[image]